# Adding space to fill array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

I am working with a javascript program that needs to be formatted a certain way.  Basically, I need to have each section of information from an array be a set length, for example 12 characters long, and no more than that.

The problem I am running into comes when a value in the array is NOT 12 characters long.  If I have a value that is less than the 12 characters the remaining character allotment needs to be filled with blank spaces.

The length of each section of information varies in size and is not always 12.  How can I add X number of blank spaces, should the length not meet the maximum requirement, for each section?

This is where I am at with adding space:

`str = str + new Array(str.length).join(' ');`

I am pretty sure what I have above is wrong but I believe I am on the right track with the .join function.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I was asked to show a wanted outcome.  It is a bit complicated because this javascript is being run out of a web report tool and not out of something like Visual Studio so its not traditional JS.

The outcome expected should look something like:

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUrr6.png)

So as shown above the data is in one line, cutting off longer strings of information or filling in blank spaces if its too short for the "column" to keep that nice even look.

Comment: Try this: `str = str + new Array(12 - str.length).join(' ');`, but make sure the length of the string is not greater than 12.

Comment: `str = str + new Array(12 - str.length).join(' ')`, or `str = str + '12 spaces '.substr(0, 12 - str.length);`.

Comment: please add some examples and the wanted outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how you're setup -- but something like the following will accept an array and return another array with all its values being 12 characters in length.

```js
var array = ['Test', 'Testing', 'Tested', 'This is not a Test'];
var adjustedArray = correctLength(array, 12);

function correctLength(array, length) {
  array.map(function(v, i) {
      if (array[i].length < length) {
        array[i] += Array((length+1) - array[i].length).join('_');
      }
      // might not need this if values are already no greater than 12
      array[i] = array[i].substring(0, length);
  });
  return array;
}

console.log(adjustedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Unfortunately, the different array values vary in set lengths that they need to be.  They are anywhere from 1, 12, 18, 16, and everywhere else.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I've updated the snippet so you can include a desired length as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and leverage the wonders of the map function:
let say your array is:

```
var myArr = ["123456789012", "12345678901", "123"];
```

now just apply this function

```
myArr.map(function(item){ //evalueate each item inside the array
    var strLength = item.length; //apply this function to each item
    if (strLength < 12){
        return item + ' '.repeat(12-item.length) //add the extra spaces as needed
    } else {
        return item; // return the item because it's length is 12 or +
    }
})
```

What you are looking for is the `' '.repeat(x)` - where x is the times you want to repeat the string you have set, it could be `'*'.repeat(2)` and you would get '**', if you want to understand more about it look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Answer (score 0):

depending on which version of javascript, this might work:

```
if (str.length < 12) str += ' '.repeat(12 - str.length);
```

Comment: what about a printf package like `sprintf-js` or `qprintf`? (the latter I wrote). 
Printf is great for columnar output; `sprintf("%12s", str)` will pad and right-align, `sprintf("%-12s", str)` will pad and left-align the string in the column.

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be dynamic.  For one record there might be a need for 4 blank spaces to fill up the 12 character limit and others it will cut off the data at 12 because there is more than that.  It will change everytime.

Comment: oh, I see.  Printf _is_ dynamic; `sprintf("%-12.12s", str)` will print exactly 12 characters, either by padding str on the right with spaces, or by trimming it.  The first 12 is the column width to pad to, the second 12 is the length to trim the string to.